# Thinkpad T460s + 19.04 = No Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad, 19.04

I have a [Thinkpad T460s](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t460s_hmm_en_sp40k04862_03.pdf) with a Ubuntu 19.04 fresh install.
Everything works fine apart from Bluetooth.
I believe this laptop has an Intel 8260 adapter (shows as device 7 but no description in lsusb)

What do I need to do to enable Bluetooth?

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7058 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1fd2:5003
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci -nn | grep -i net,lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
[    0.130268] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.182718] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.797020] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    2.988503] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.105794] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
```

rfkill list

```
0: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: An Intel bluetooth device would show a VID of 8087 in lsusb results

Comment: Do you think it might be a hardware issue then? WiFi works fine

Comment: It might be an issue with the USB bus or that wifi card doesn't have the Bluetooth option

Comment: I'm fairly sure the card does has Bluetooth as it's sold having it. If it's an issue with the USB Bus, is there anyway to diagnose that or fix it?